# What is the technical term for a Mac app that resides in the menu bar?

Tags: macos, icons, menubar

I come from iOS to the Mac and want to make a simple utility that lives in the menu bar at the top right.

Some "menu bar apps" open a "window" like a speech bubble. The app is in the "window". When you click outside the "window" the "window" closes.

Here is a good looking example from Crashlytics Mac app:

[image: Crashlytics Mac app]

Found this [example](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem/) project but I want to learn more about it and what it is called officially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS X [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Intro/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000894-TP6) call them [menu bar extras](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Characteristics/Characteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002721-SW1).